# Numpy: Read in an arbitrary number of .txt files and save the data in one numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, genfromtxt, txt

Excuse me if this has been asked previously, I could not find anything.

I am trying to define a function that takes an arbitrary number of .txt files that look like these

[image]

reads them, concatenates all the rows and saves it into one numpy array. This works for one .txt file. As soon as i use two files I get `array([nan, nan])` as a return, with three files `array([nan, nan, nan])`, etc.

```
import numpy as np

def readInSpectra(*files):
    raw = np.genfromtxt(files[0], skip_header=0, delimiter='\t')
    for i in range(1, len(files)):
        raw_i = np.genfromtxt(files[i], skip_header=0, delimiter='\t')
        raw = np.vstack((raw, raw_i))
    return raw

files = ('./file1.txt', './file2.txt', './file3.txt')

test = readInSpectra(files)
```

Comment: Why are you unpacking your input tuple ? Python will consider each element of your tuple as a different argument.

Comment: just use `def readInSpectra(files)` instead of `def readInSpectra(*files)`.

Comment: True, that works. I googled for "python function with unknown number of arguments" and found that I should use a tuple, like as an argument and write `function(*argument)`.

I am sure it is still strong "not the way to go" an unelegant but it does now what I wanted.

Comment: @Wulfram You can still use your original version, just call it in another way (see my edit)

Comment: @Wulfram you do not have an unknown number of arguments, you have 1 argument with multiple elements in it, in this case 1 tuple of string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure, but I think the repeated `vstack` is a problem because the shape of the arrays change. Have you tried:

```
def readInSpectra(*files):
    
    stacking = tuple(np.genfromtxt(file, skip_header=0, delimiter='\t')
                     for file in files)

    return np.vstack(stacking)
```

**EDIT**: I think you should call the function this way

```
test = readInSpectra(*files)
```

or

```
test = readInSpectra('./file1.txt', './file2.txt', './file3.txt')
```

Comment: Then I also get `array([[nan, nan, nan]])` as a return.

Comment: My answer worked, but I suggest you take advice from @obchardon

Comment: @ted930511 You're right, the problem was how the function was called

Answer (score 1):

Both should work, I suggest you do second as suggested by @obchardon

```
import numpy as np


def readInSpectra_0(*files):
    files = files[0]
    raw = np.genfromtxt(files[0], skip_header=0, delimiter='\t')
    for i in range(1, len(files)):
        raw_i = np.genfromtxt(files[i], skip_header=0, delimiter='\t')
        raw = np.vstack((raw, raw_i))
    return raw

def readInSpectra_1(files):
    
    stacking = tuple(np.genfromtxt(file, skip_header=0, delimiter='\t')
                     for file in files)

    return np.vstack(stacking)

#files = ('file1.txt', 'file2.txt')
files = ('./file1.txt', './file2.txt', './file3.txt')


test = readInSpectra_1(files)
```